# Extra Junk at the end of [99synaptic] file

Tags: apt, unicode, synaptic

When I try to launch synaptic I get this error:

```
E: Syntax error /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99synaptic:1: Extra junk at end of file"
```

[I found out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342179/how-to-solve-extra-junk-at-end-of-file-when-using-apt) that semicolons could be missed in that file, but when try to open the 99synaptic file with mousepad text editor I get this error: "The document was not UTF-8 valid"
while if I use visual studio code, I can view the file but it contains this:

```
_��~D�L��M�9�I���K6Y��T�#�
```

Comment: Get the file from a good working server and replace it, seems to be totally messed up.

Comment: Mine is a single line like this `APT::Install-Recommends "true";`. Check yours by `cat`ting to the terminal. You can try `cat -tev ...` for detecting any undisplayable (strange) characters in the file.